# Failed to build libmysql on windows using vc2008

Tags: mysql, c, visual-c++

I want to build libmysql.dll, so I got source code mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src.zip from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/.
Then cmake-gui.exe to configure and generate vc 2008 sln, leave all settings default.
Then got errors and warnings when building, like this:

```
mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\include\thr_cond.h(109) : error C2065: “ETIMEDOUT”: 未声明的标识符(an unspecified identifier)  
mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\include\thr_rwlock.h(80) : warning C4013: “TryAcquireSRWLockShared” 未定义(not defined)
mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\include\thr_rwlock.h(102) : warning C4013: “TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive” 未定义(not defined)
```

I searched the source, and find ETIMEDOUT is defined in my_pthread.h, so I include this header in thr_cond.h, but still error.
And TryAcquireSRWLockShared and TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive seem only supported on Win7 and later !

Do I have done something wrong?
How can I build libmysql?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is in general a very bad idea to use a C++ compiler to compile C code. There are many major and subtle differences between the languages.

Comment: @Olaf , vc's compiler cl.exe can also compile c code, compile c when the file is xxx.c while c++ when the file is xxx.cpp, it'a not the problem, I think

Comment: Well, as the current standard is [C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) and VC does not even support C99, it actually cannot. Just read here and you will find a bunch of problems with that. However, I cannot help you further. That was more a general hint, triggered by some keywords and the tag.

Comment: @Olaf, compiled binary can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/. It means libmysql can be compiled with vc. I just want to compile by myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download the previous version ([6.0.2](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2.zip)), it doesn's use the TryAcquireSRWLockShared() API function.
With a few minor tweeks, it compiles clean with MSVC 2008.

Here are the modifications (based on the extracted zip file root):

1. Replace line 306 of include/config-win.h with:

   ```
   // avoid annoying warning
   #ifndef HAVE_COMPRESS
   #   define HAVE_COMPRESS
   #endif
   ```
2. Comment lines 350-367 of CMakeLists.txt (CPack instructions cause CMake to fail)
3. Follow instructions in BUILD.win